# How to run history command in script

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I have one script like

```
history
```

*test.sh file* in that I just put **history**

Now I run **sh test.sh**

Then it gives error like :  ***history: command not found***

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score -1):

history is a command of the shell, so it should not look for it as if it were an external command (like ls)

I made a quick test and did not experience your problem, although I needed to use

set -o history

in order for history to display.

Can you provide further details?